# Bridge between incompatible implementations in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, design-patterns

I'm trying to create a bridge between two services with an incompatible interface.

`ServiceType` is an argument from the user, so it has to be validated during runtime.

The best I could think of is this. But there are several problems. I will have to create a similar method like `find` on the `SericeByType` object for each function on `CampaignService | LeadService` and the result from that function is a union of `CampaignModel | LeadModel`.

Is there a better way how to do it?

```
interface CampaignModel {
  id: number
}

class CampaignService {
  public async find(startId: number, limit: number): Promise<CampaignModel[]> {
    return [];
  }
}

interface LeadModel {
  id: string
}

class LeadService {
  public async find(startId: string, limit: number): Promise<LeadModel[]> {
    return [];
  }
}

type ServiceType = 'Campaign' | 'Lead'

class SericeByType {
  private readonly campaignService: CampaignService = new CampaignService();
  private readonly leadService: LeadService = new LeadService();

  public async find(type: ServiceType, startId: number | string, limit: number) {
    if (this.isCampaign(type)) {
      return this.campaignService.find(startId as number, limit);
    } else if (this.isLead(type)) {
      return this.leadService.find(startId as string, limit);
    } else {
      throw new Error();
    }
  }

  private isCampaign(type: ServiceType) {
    return type === 'Campaign';
  }

  private isLead(type: ServiceType) {
    return type === 'Lead';
  }
}

const service = new SericeByType();
service.find('Campaign', 16, 10);
service.find('Lead', 'xxxawf', 10);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJwLYAc7AOYgCyA9gCYQA2yA3gLABQyywpAXMiAK4YBG0DAXwYMEFOAGdxaTDnwgAytABuwJDQZMsnHhVXIJATxAJkMUKQAU4sHChgAkmw7c+UADTJdGYGHZde0ACU7AAKUMTe4hAAPOjYuAQk5BQA2gC6AHzqjEzIUBBgnFAgyOkA3BrIQvTVDKCQsIgoADIQcKRJlNlMLOzWUKB4gsL0ohJSre2KUCpqdDlaOnqGxqbmVjZ2jn1gAyB4Hl4+fi5BoeGRMZMdZJTpWfO5eQVFJeWV1bX0YAZYKNOzCAAFV+KAAvMgAORxWQESHIAA+UOukJGY0kyGmqggACEDCC-t1kFgBko4JBnu1iCAKAZkAgZAkFMpsewYUyAdjkBCQBAAO7SeJyTlICyBCoLUnklD5Kk0ukUNqkEUQdjXFXcjj85Dqlmi8UjTTaXQmFYmMwgSw-P7sFUEiAeay2BxOfyuRHIfqDQ7Aby+ZwBKCBIk9GDICxgAAWwHEADoY+y5BHQYFg48ns9CsVkFGY7GGUKCCrYxbLE6tqR9FI3dAfX6DTkmAJkJQoswwxHo3GY9dk39UyHcvksyVc3HFVM9RAS+tyy6q57dt7PL6fA2ns3Wyh008o+EBbyBQBRKDhKBiiUbj6G4lSikJxlJ62qzFT+1pypMYevHOg7lgiFoUfOFLyqG8SWAMl73EXtn1tN8U0Hb9s2ff9AJRUDPjRalrE9KdNUPV8BiQPF7QvBgohmbEZ0tCwgMLEBIQ8ABGAA2FiAAYG0owEaMsSEUQ8SEAA9RLgPkYCY5BmK4iUgA)

Comment: It's not really clear what is a given in this code, where there are two things that are incompatible but need to be used in the same manner, and what is the code of the bridge.

Comment: You seem to be looking for an overload or a generic

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXKjQW) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz this is really interesting approach, thank you very much. Right now, I'm not sure if I can utilize it, but it is something I will think about.

Comment: Can you articulate what you're not sure about? By what criteria would you select whether an answer does or does not fully address your question?  I could write up an answer explaining how my suggested solution works, but if you don't know if you'd accept it or not I don't really want to spend too much time on it.  Please consider clarifying the question so that others can know how to respond.